# BootStrap 3.X Radio ButtonGroup - OnClick Trigger Method That Gets Currently Selected Button

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a button group like so:

```
<div id="matchMode" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default center-block">
        <input type="radio" name="matchMode" value="0">All
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default active center-block">
        <input type="radio" name="matchMode" value="1">Filtered
    </label>
</div>
```

I need the buttons to be clickable so that I can trigger some code to refresh a data grid as soon as they are clicked.  I have tried the following:

```
$(function () {
    $("#matchMode .btn").click(function() {
        RefreshDataGrid();
    })
});
```

That *seems* to work but `RefreshDataGrid()` looks like this:

```
function RefreshDataGrid() {
    var mode = $('#matchMode > .btn.active :radio').val();
    //some code that uses the var mode to refresh a data grid.
}
```

What I'm trying to get at is that the event handler seems to happen before the Bootstrap change in classes for `active` between buttons happens in the DOM.  This causes my selection to be incorrect and I have to click on a button at least **twice** to get the proper data in the data grid.

What is the proper way to resolve this?  I feel like it should be simpler and I am making it very complicated.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You are almost to the target !

```
 $(function () {
            $("#matchMode .btn").click(function () {
                RefreshDataGrid(this);
            })
        });

        function RefreshDataGrid(data) {
            var mode = data.lastElementChild.value;
            //some code that uses the var mode to refresh a data grid.
        }
```

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/IJy7D6kUNd)

Answer (score 0):

Why not to attach event to `change`, and check the selected element by `checked`:

```
$(function () {
    function RefreshDataGrid() {
        var mode = $('#matchMode input:checked').val();
        alert(mode);
    }

    $("#matchMode input:radio").change(function() {
        RefreshDataGrid();
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zoyL205h/).